# Is there a way to create a looped array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Alright, so I've got a question that I doubt is an actual c++ feature, but it's worth a shot... I'm creating a terminal-text-based mancala game, and I'm using an array to keep track of the points in each cup of the board, I was wondering if there is any way that if the user triggers the, let's say, "boardArray[13]" cup, and the flow of the array is going chronologically, I want the value of 
"boardArray[13]" to loop back to the beginning of the board, and start distributing back to "boardArray[1]". I doubt that makes sense, let me know if you need me to clarify. I basically want an array that goes

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14, RESET 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14, RESET
1,2,3...
```

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you're asking, but I imagine using the modulo operator on the variable used to index the array may be what you want.

Comment: *"let me know if you need me to clarify"* Yes, a clarification would help. Maybe you could demonstrate what you need with code?

Comment: Maybe you just want to put a range based for loop inside a second loop. I assume that at some point / condition met you would want to stop looping...

Comment: You want an array that keeps looping?

Comment: Search term: "Circular Buffer".

Comment: Also note that arrays are 0-based so, for `<type> boardArray[14];` your indexes would be 0 - 13.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in array type won't do this. If you want to, it's pretty easy to create a type with an overloaded operator to do the job though.

```
template <std::size_t N>
class LoopedArray {
    int data[N];
public:
    int &operator[](size_t index) { 
        return data[index % N];
    }
};

int main() {
    LoopedArray<13> la;

    // put known values into the array:
    for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
        la[i] = i;

    // demonstrate reading the data with "looping" of the index:
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        std::cout << la[i] << "\t";
}
```

It's open to more question whether I'd really recommend doing this, but it certainly can be done, and I guess I can believe it could be useful...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "looped array" for this, such a thing doesn't exist in C++ as far as I know.

You can achive the same effect very easiely by looping your index.

Instead of using `yourArray[i]` just use `yourArray[i%14]` to only access the first 14 elements of it.

Comment: Depending on how long this runs, how fast it iterates, and and the size of the index variable, sometimes it is better to `if (++i >= 14) i = 0;` to protect the index from overflowing.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, thats the exact thing I was wondering!

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not very familiar with the mancala game, but as far as I understand the user would select one of the 14 cups and you would loop to redistribute the pieces. So the highest index that will ever be reached will be 14+numberOfPieces, which is small enough for all popolar index types.

Answer (score 0):

Such an array doesn't exist in C++ that I'm aware of (or all of programming for that matter).

What you could try is a linked list:

```
class node {
public:
    node* next;
    int value;

}
```

Then, link several together:

```
node root;
node* current=&root
for(i=0;i<14;i++) {
    current->value=0; // for initialization
    current->next = new node;
    current = current->next;
}
current->next = root;
```

These items will be linked in a loop. You can access them like this

```
int value = current->value;
for(int i=0;i<value;i++) {
    current = current->next;
    current.value +=1;
}
```

Of course this gets quite messy, particularly when you're trying to delete it.

```
void DeleteList(node *n,node *root) {
    if(n == root) {
        return;
    }
    DeleteList(n->next,root);
    delete n;
}
```

That's just an example, but it can have lots of problems fast.

What I guess I really should recommend is similar to what [AlbertM recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55289662/10957435), but wrapped in a nice function for you:

```
void addPoints(int arr[], int cup, int arrlen) {
    int value = arr[cup]; // stored for later    
    arr[cup] = 0; // since we are emptying the cup

    for(int i=0; i<value;i++) {
        arr[(cup+i)%arrlen] += 1;
    }

}
```